# Remove non-alpha characters before a character from every line of a text file

Tags: regex, perl, sed, email-address

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
13foobar@example.com
foo.bar3@example2.com
qwerty-1@dept.example3.com
```

How can I use **sed** or **perl** to remove all non-alpha characters before the @ sign. I.e. the desired output would be:

```
foobar@example.com
foobar@example2.com
qwerty@dept.example3.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Input**

```
13foobar@example.com
foo.bar3@example2.com
qwerty-1@dept.example3.com
```

**Perl one-liner**

```
perl -ne 'my ($user,$host) = split /\@/; $user =~ s/[\W\d]//g; print $user . "@" . $host;'
```

**In action**

```
cat input | perl -ne 'my ($user,$host) = split /\@/; $user =~ s/[\W\d]//g; print $user . "@" . $host;'
```

**Output**

```
foobar@example.com
foobar@example2.com
qwerty@dept.example3.com
```

Answer (score 1):

The following one-liner should suffice.

```
perl -pe 's/[^a-z]+(?=[^@\n]*@)//g'
```

Comment: Generally speaking, this a bad approach since it's O(N^2). However, since the OP's input will be limited in length in practice, that's not relevant for him.

Comment: @ikegami, In general I certainly agree, but for this case it would be alright.